# Handling Policy based exception using MS Entlib 5.0

Tags: exception, enterprise-library

I would want to learn about MS Entlib 5.0. Frankly I have no idea what it is. Please provide me the links to start exploring. Then I Would have to evaluate whether the following requirements can be met using MS Entlib 5.0

1.Policy based exception handling & logging into both file and DB
2.Capability to enable detailed logging through trace/debug.
3Capability to overwrite business exception raised from stored proc or BO with a localized exception message for UI display

Please provide your valuable inputs on the above requirements.

Thanks in Advance,
Manasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manasa, EntLib can help with all 3 scenarios you inquired about.

EntLib is a collection of pluggable *application blocks* that address cross-cutting concerns, such as logging, exception management, data access, data validation etc. EntLib is configuration-driven (supporting both external configuration sources and programmatic config via fluent interface). It's a mature library which is currently in its 5th release and is built by [Microsoft patterns & practices group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/practices).

I recommend you start with the [Enterprise Library Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953181%28PandP.50%29.aspx), in particular Chapters 1, 3 and 4. Then proceed with the [Hands-On Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec). Based on your requirements, you would want to explore the Logging and Exception Handling set of exercises.

Additional resources can be found at:

- [MSDN EntLib Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/entlib) is the home page where all final releases and documentation can be
  found.
- [EntLib Community Site](http://entlib.codeplex.com) - includes preview releases, ongoing work, community forum, issue database and other useful resources.

Comment: Thanks for the info Melnik. I need to have working code samples for all the three scenarios. Hence I would try the hands on labs you have provided. In addition to this, If you can provide me some examples, it would be great. Thanks a lot

Comment: All hands-on labs contain examples, starting with basic and going into more comprehensive. Additional examples are provided for the Developer's Guide: http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5%20Developer%20Notes&referringTitle=Home

Comment: After I install the hands on LAbs, I am not sure how exactly to use it using VS2010, Can you pleaee guide me or any document about the steps?

Comment: Open the VS solution file for a specific exercise for the language of choice - C# or VB. They are written for VS2008, but VS2010 will automatically convert them. Then just follow lab instructions, which are available in PDF and XPS formats.